# pip is installing python libraries to a different path

Tags: python, pip, module, package, conda

On my linux machine.

If I run `pip list -v`, all of the packages are installed in the location:

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

But when I go to install a new package for example `sudo pip install numpy`.
And then I run `pip list -v` I see that the numpy package location is:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages pip`

Then in the python when I try and import the package with:

`import numpy as np`

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

---

I am guessing this is because of the reason I described above about the different location that pip has installed the package to.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo pip install numpy` will install numpy globally for all user, I think your code might running in a virtual environment so it cannot find the package you installed in the global.

If you running the Python code in an IDE, like PyCharm, the IDE will automatically create a virtual environment for you, the packages you installed globally are isolated by virtual environment. So to resolve the problem, you need install numpy in your IDE's environment.

If you are not using any IDE, just running the code in your Linux terminal, you can try install numpy using `python -m pip install numpy`, this will install the numpy for your current Linux user and environment. Or you can use `sudo su` to enter your root user mode to run that code. Your code should be able to find the numpy in root mode.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me. In the end I just installed miniconda.